# logback printing the logs in random manner

Tags: logback

When the load is running the logs are not generated in order as per timestamp.

We are using the below logback configuration:

```
<appender name="messageResponse" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <append>true</append>
    <file>message-response.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>message-response-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```